# How to enforce Serilog tagging to an enum

Tags: c#, enums, serilog

I am replacing our log4net logger to structured logging using Serilog. 
I want to enforce the tagging in the code using an Enum but I'm having some difficulties how to do so.

For now my log look like that:

```
logger.ErrorFormat("Proxy Logic for the Item {Item} failed. Swallow exception", Item);
```

When `ErrorFormat` signutare is

```
void ErrorFormat(string format, params object[] args);
```

but I don't know how to replace `Item` to something like `LogTags.TagA`. When TagA is an Enum which will give me the way to enforce a uniform standard for my tagging.

so it would look like:

```
public enum LogTags
{
TagA,
...
}
public class Foo
{
     public void DoError()
     {
     logger.ErrorFormat("Proxy Logic for the Item {@LogTags.TagA} failed. Swallow exception", Item);
     }
}
```

What is the best practice to achieve such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property names in Serilog need to be simple, non-dotted identifiers, so a name like `Enum.LogTags.Item` won't work directly.

You can force this nesting with something like the pattern below, if a simple name is inadequate:

```
logger.ErrorFormat(
  "Proxy Logic for the Item {@Enum} failed. Swallow exception",
  new { LogTags = new { Item }});
```

Comment: thanks on the answer, but it wasn't my intention. I edited my post to be more clear. I want to enforce a **standard** for the tags. Because later on I want to write quires on the Serilog DB sink that will accommodate with these tags.

Comment: NW - is it possible you're looking for `Log.ForContext()`?

Comment: no...I rewrite the question. I want to enforce a tagging standard. I think maybe its just not possible

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve is to centrally define logging tags. In that case what you want is to use string interpolation for creating the format string:

```
logger.ErrorFormat($"Proxy Logic for the Item {{{LogTags.TagA}}} failed. Swallow exception", Item);
```